# compare two json in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I need compare two json objects which are inside of an array, it's a function with two params, (two json array), i need compare those arrays and verify when two fields are equal(property named domainLogin), and push a field to one of the jsons (evaluo='true'), here is the code that I have:

```
 function CompararEvaluadores(todos, evaluo) {



            for (i = 0; i < todos.length; i += 1) {
                for (J = 0; J < evaluo.length; J += 1) {
                    if (todos[i].DomainLogin === evaluo[J].domainLogin) {
                        todos[i].push({ evaluo: 'true' })
                    }

                }

            }


    }
```

dosent work, please some help, Im new in nodejs  thank....

Comment: [dosent work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a helpful description of the problem. What do you **expect** to happen? What **actually** happens? How are these **different**? Are any errors displayed?

Comment: You are using `async` **and** `new Promise` which is pointlessly [nesting promises](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

Comment: For that matter, you aren't doing anything asynchronous in your code in the first place. There doesn't seem to be any point in using promises in the first place.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: You also have implicit globals, which is just asking for trouble (especially if your code actually was asynchronous). You should declare your variables and [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to append the true to each object, right? This is how you should do it:

```
async function CompararEvaluadores(todos, evaluo) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // console.log(valor2)
                for (i = 0; i < todos.length; i += 1) {
                    for (J = 0; J < evaluo.length; J += 1) {
                        if (todos[i].DomainLogin === evaluo[J].domainLogin) {
                            todos[i].evaluo = true
                        }

                    }

                }
                console.log(todos)
                resolve(todos)
            })
        }
```

Another approach would be:

```
async function CompararEvaluadores(todos, evaluo) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var result = todos.map(elem=>(evaluo.some(elem2=>elem.DomainLogin === elem2.domainLogin) ? {...elem,evaluo:true} : elem))
                return resolve(result);
            })
        }
```

And you have to use it like:

```
var callFunction = async(todos,evaluo)=>
{
  var todos = await CompararEvaluadores(todos,evaluo);
  // use todos
}
```

Comment: dosent work, dont add the fiel, the field's name is evaluo=true

Comment: So you want to add a boolean rather than string? I edited the code.

Comment: what do you mean by saying 'better way'?

Comment: m starting at node and I've tried many ways and don't work it

Comment: I'm working on another approach, will update the code.

Comment: you are my salvation, thank!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Updated code, please check and accept as answer if it works

Comment: hi thank, but dosent works, the esctructure is not right..thank